# intelephense.index.workspace not found

Tags: vscode-extensions, php-intelephense

I have been working with PHP Intelephense on a project for quite a while.
After a recent reboot of my computer, I noticed the usual functionality stopped working:
no more auto completion, functions are no longer recognised, ...

Thus, I tried to run a re-indexation via `ctrl-shift-p` Intelephense: Index workspace.
Which results in

```
Command 'Intelephense: Index workspace' resulted in an error (command 'intelephense.index.workspace' not found)
```

I tried to re-install the plugin in VS code, but no luck.
Any suggestions?

My VS info is:

```
Version: 1.72.2 (Universal)
Commit: d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075
Date: 2022-10-12T22:16:30.254Z
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 21.6.0
Sandboxed: No
```

Intelephense version is `v1.10.2`.

Edit:
Just found out that reverting to `v1.9.5` solves the issue. So it is probably caused by an intelephense update.